# Chrome Extension Storing Custom Object Type Strips Prototype Methods

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have created a custom object that I am using in my extension. When I save objects of the type Group (my object type) and then later pull those objects out of storage, it appears that the prototype methods are no longer present. Now I read in the documentation that objects serialize down to object literals `{}` and I can't seem to figure out how to keep the methods with the objects. I have provided the code of the group class below. When I try and use one of the methods from the file below on an object that was retrieved from storage, I get an error that the function does not exist. I used a for in loop to loop through all of the properties and the object has the name and urls property. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Group.js:

```
// Create the Group class
var Group = function (name, urls) {
  this.name = name;
  this.urls = urls;
};

// Clears all urls from the group
Group.prototype.clearUrls = function () {
  this.urls = [];
};

// Adds the specified url to the group
Group.prototype.addUrl = function (url) {
  this.urls.append(url);
};

// Removes the specified url from the group
Group.prototype.removeUrl = function (url) {
  this.urls = this.urls.filter(function(_url){
    return url !== _url;
  });
};

// Renames the group
Group.prototype.rename = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
};

// Checks whether or not the group contains the specified url
// Returns either true or false
Group.prototype.containsUrl = function (url) {
  var contains = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.urls.length; i++) {
    if (this.urls[i] === url) {
      contains = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return contains;
};
```

EDIT:

Here is the background.js script, it shows how the object is retrieved and then how it is called later in the script. It fails when it receives the addUrl message and attempts to call `containsUrl()` on currentGroup.

```
// Global Variables
var currentGroup;
var groups = [];
var options = [];

// Short hand function to save the current data to storage
var saveData = function () {
  // Save default options, currrentGroup, and groups
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'options': options, 'currentGroup': currentGroup, 'groups': groups}, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error("Could not save because: " + chrome.runtime.lastError);
    }
  });
}

// On start query for saved data to make sure data is current
chrome.storage.sync.get(function(items) {
  // Check if there are groups
  if (items['groups']) { // Set the groups
    groups = items['groups'];
  } else { // Create default group and add to list of groups
    currentGroup = new Group('default', []);
    groups = [currentGroup];
  }

  // Check for current group, if none set to first available group
  if (items['currentGroup']) {
    currentGroup = items['currentGroup'];
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(currentGroup));
  } else {
    currentGroup = groups[0];
  }

  // Check for the options
  if (items['options']) {
    options = items['options'];
  } else {
    // No options, set the default options and save them
    options['overrideHomepages'] = true;
  }

  saveData();

  // After data has been fetched bring up the tabs
  chrome.tabs.query({'currentWindow': true}, function(tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < currentGroup.urls.length; i++) {
      if (options['overrideHomepages']) {
        if (tabs[i].url.length > 0) {
          chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {'url': currentGroup.urls[i]});
        } else {
          chrome.tabs.create({'url': currentGroup.urls[i]});
        }
      } else { // Don't override homepages or open tabs
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': currentGroup.urls[i]});
      }
      currentGroup.urls[i]
    }
  }); // End tabs.query

}); // End storage.sync.get

// Add message listener
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

  // If add url was sent
  if (request.message === 'addUrl') {
    console.log('Recieved message: ' + request.message);
    // Check if the group contains the url already
    if (currentGroup.containsUrl(sender.url) === false) {
      currentGroup.addUrl(sender.url);
      saveData();
      sendResponse({'message': 'Saved ' + sender.url});
    }
  }

  // If remove url was sent
  if (request.message === 'removeUrl') {
    // Check if the group contains the url
    if (currentGroup.containsUrl(sender.url)) {
      currentGroup.removeUrl(sender.url);
      saveData();
      sendResponse({'message': 'Removed ' + sender.url})
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Not much clear about your question, could you please provide more code like how you use Group.js?

Comment: I edited the post and added the background.js script to give it more context

Comment: What's the error info? When you call `currentGroup.containsUrl`, does `currentGroup` has been initialized? When will message sent to background page?

Comment: The message is sent to the background.js script when a button on the popup.html file is pressed, I have checked and the object is initialized when it is pulled out of storage.sync, the error when I try and call the function is `TypeError: currentGroup.containsUrl is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe currently `chrome.storage` is only used to save key-value items, not including prototype/functions. However, I didn't find any official docs about this.

One workaround would be using `Group.prototype.containsUrl.call(currentGroup, sender.url)`, it allows you to invoke `containsUrl` with specifying the context for `"this"`.

Comment: Thank you! This allowed the function to be called and it appears to be working so far. I spent hours trying to figure this, very much appreciated!

Comment: @SamG, glad to help, however, I'm not sure about that, since `chrome.storage` can be used to save objects, but it seems only key-value is supported. We can wait and see if someone else could give a better explanation.

Comment: For now I will leave your answer as the correct one as it is the only solution that has worked for me so far, if another better solution comes along I will update! Thanks again, I have been able to make progress now that I am past that bug